# License issues re: using Angularjs and Bootstrap in a desktop app

Tags: legal, mit-license, angularjs, desktop-application, bootstrap

I'm a web developer and I've been asked to write a desktop app. The languages and libraries that I'm most familiar with are standard web tools (Javascript, Angular, Bootstrap). I'd like to use these same tools.

Lately there's been considerable interest in using web tools for Desktop, and frameworks have appeared that make it technically feasible.

I wonder, though, about legal feasibility. Are there "gotchas" with the licenses on Angular and Bootstrap that would complicate using them on the Desktop? Can these libraries be packaged into standalone applications, downloaded, and run offline, outside of a browser? Or can they only be run in the standard web app paradigm (i.e. loaded from a server, and run online in an internet-connected browser)?

These questions may have obvious answers, but I wanted to be crystal clear about them before I start the project.

Comment: well... most of those questions will depend on the license being used by each, wouldn't it? as well as how the app would be distributed.

Comment: You need to specify the licenses you are using and how you are using them. Until you do, it is *far* too broad of a question to be reasonably answered as there are lots of different licenses out there with different gotchas.

Comment: Given both licenses are MIT, the question with the additional information provided would be a duplicate of [What exactly does the condition in the MIT license imply?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/178486/what-exactly-does-the-condition-in-the-mit-license-imply)

Comment: I am curious as to how you would use AngularJs in a desktop app, unless you have a browser component in the app ...

Answer (score 1):

On further inspection, [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE) and [Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/LICENSE) both use the [MIT License](https://tldrlegal.com/license/mit-license). This is a very permissive license that allows software to be distributed in commercial applications, so long as the license text is included. I see no reason why these libraries couldn't be included in a desktop app.

If I'm wrong, someone please correct me!